# Getting unknown error while going on Live server - Cs-Cart

Tags: php, mysql, cs-cart

On local server its working perfectly but on server it generates below error. @CS-Cart

```
TypeError

Message
Tygh\Storefront\RelationsManager::__construct(): Argument #3 ($schema) must be of type array, bool given, called in /home/u434437461/domains/innbzz.online/public_html/app/Tygh/Providers/StorefrontProvider.php on line 136

Error at
app/Tygh/Storefront/RelationsManager.php, line: 47

Backtrace
File:app/Tygh/Providers/StorefrontProvider.php
Line:136
Function:__construct

File:app/lib/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php
Line:118
Function:Tygh\Providers\{closure}

File:app/Tygh/Application.php
Line:135
Function:offsetGet

File:app/Tygh/Providers/StorefrontProvider.php
Line:92
Function:offsetGet

File:app/lib/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php
Line:118
Function:Tygh\Providers\{closure}

File:app/Tygh/Application.php
Line:135
Function:offsetGet

File:app/Tygh/Providers/StorefrontProvider.php
Line:72
Function:offsetGet

File:app/lib/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php
Line:118
Function:Tygh\Providers\{closure}

File:app/Tygh/Application.php
Line:135
Function:offsetGet

File:app/Tygh/Providers/StorefrontProvider.php
Line:158
Function:offsetGet

File:app/lib/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php
Line:118
Function:Tygh\Providers\{closure}

File:app/Tygh/Application.php
Line:135
Function:offsetGet

File:app/functions/fn.init.php
Line:634
Function:offsetGet

File:app/functions/fn.init.php
Line:1200
Function:fn_init_layout

File:init.php
Line:179
Function:fn_init

File:index.php
Line:24
Function:require
```

Database connected. Execution is working but in flow of execution, I am getting this error.

Comment: Open `/home/u434437461/domains/innbzz.online/public_html/app/Tygh/Providers/StorefrontProvider.php` and see what the line has. From the message sounds like a query failed. Maybe different mysql drivers between machines, different DB schemas, something else?

Comment: This might be due to different versions of php, you might have php 8.0+ version on live server thus these errors.